# Proving positivity of the exponential function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series, special-functions, exponential-function

**Question**. Without using the semigroup property ($\mathrm{e}^{x}\mathrm{e}^{y}=\mathrm{e}^{x+y}$),
how can we show that $\mathrm{e}^{x}>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ only by using the series expansion?

**Explanation**.
From the series expansion of $\mathrm{e}^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we see that $\mathrm{e}^{x}>0$ for $x\geq0$.
Thus, if the series becomes negative, this can only happen for negative values of $x$.
So proving $\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ for $x>0$ will complete the proof.
As the series converges uniformly on any compact interval $I\subset\mathrm{R}$, we can rearrange the terms of the series and write
$\mathrm{e}^{-x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}g_{n}(x)$ for $x\geq0$, where $g_{n}(x):=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\Big(\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}-\frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}\Big)$ for $x\geq0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Obviously, $g_{n}$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$ and $g_{n}(1)>\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}$.

I need to prove the following.

**Claim**. There exists an increasing divergent sequence $\{\xi_{n}\}\subset(0,\infty)$ such that $g_{n}$ is decreasing on $[0,\xi_{n}]$ with $g_{n}(\xi_{n})>0$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Strengthened Claim**. $\xi_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Do you have  a special reason for not using that property?

Comment: @PhoemueX Exactly, the functions I am working are of the series form and they do not have such nice properties. When I plot their graphics, they seem to be positive everywhere but I could not handle it. This pushed me back to the exponential function.

Comment: Then say what functions you are working on! What is the point of asking us to do something else that you don't actually want?

Comment: @user21820 I am working with the Mittag-Leffler function. Since not much people is familiar with it, I just gave its particular form.

Comment: Showing that $e^x>0$ for all $x$ depends on what definition/characterization you have for $e^x$. And if that's not even the function you care about, then it depends upon what definition/characterization you have for your actual function. As it is, it is literally impossible to help you here.

Comment: @GregMartin That is the usual exponential function, there is no different definition or characterization for it. I am only asking an alternative proof of proving its positivity. Don't you wonder to know it?

Comment: My intension is to show $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\big(\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}-\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\big)>0$ for $0<x<\xi_{n}$, where $\{\xi_{k}\}_{0}^{\infty}$ is an increasing divergent sequence of positive number. I also feel like $\xi_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}$ for $n=0,1,\cdots$ would work. So letting $n\to\infty$ will prove the claim.

Comment: With $p_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$, it is true that $p_n$ is always positive when $n$ is even while $p_n$ has a unique (negative) root when $n$ is odd (this can be proved by induction). If you can show that that negative root tends to $-\infty$, I think you're done. The identities $p_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n!}+p_{n-1}(x)$ and $p'_n(x) = p_{n-1}(x)$ are useful here.

Comment: (Side note: just as there are many equivalent definitions for $e$, there are indeed many equivalent definitions for $e^x$. One common method of building up from fundamentals defines $e^x$ as the inverse function to $\int_1^x \frac{dt}t$, for example. So it is indeed important for you to tell us that you are using the Maclaurin series definition of $e^x$—particularly since you are trying to prove something that in most situations would be obvious, thus indicating that you are indeed interested in the foundations.)

Comment: A very related article is the following. S. M. Zemyan, On the zeroes of the {$N$}th partial sum of the exponential series, Amer. Math. Monthly 112 (2005), no. 10, 891--909.

Comment: @GregMartin I could show that the negative roots are in decreasing order but I could **not** yet show that they tend to $-\infty$. However, I am **not** sure it is enough for us to say that $\mathrm{e}^{x}>0$ for $x<0$. This says that $p_{n}(x)>0$ for $x>r_{n}$ (for odd indices). But taking limit as $n\to\infty$ takes us to $\mathrm{e}^{x}\geq0$ for $x>-\infty$ from which I **cannot** say that it is positive. Do you have any idea for it?

Comment: Fair point. But this isn't too hard: for a fixed negative $x$, the sequence $\{p_n(x)\colon n$ odd$\}$ is increasing for $n>|x|$. So if one of the terms is strictly positive, so is the limit.

Answer (score 3):

**A hyperbolic trigonometry approach.** Set
$$
C(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\quad\text{and}\quad S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}
$$
It suffices to show that $C(x)>S(x)$, for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

First observe that: $C'(x)=S(x)$ and $S'(x)=C(x)$. Then observe that
$$
\big(C^2(x)-S^2(x)\big)'=2\big(C(x)C'(x)-S(x)S'(x)\big)=2\big(C(x)S(x)-S(x)C(x)\big)=0,
$$
and hence 
$$
C^2(x)-S^2(x)=C^2(0)-S^2(0)=1.
$$
Thus, for every $x\in\mathbb R$,
$$
C(x)=\sqrt{S^2(x)+1}>S(x).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Using termwise differentiation one finds that $\exp$ satisfies the linear differential equation $y'=y$, which obvioulsy satisfies the assumptions of the existence and uniqueness theorem. The function $y_0(x):\equiv0$ is a solution, and no other solution can cross the graph of $y_0$. It follows that $x\mapsto e^x$, which is positive when $x=0$, is positive on its full domain ${\mathbb R}$.

Comment: That's perfectly correct. However, I cannot use this for my purpose as my functions do not satisfy a homogeneous linear equation. But as I have mentioned before, the proof is correct.

Comment: In order to prove the Uniqueness part of Picard-Lindelof you NEED the semigroup properties of the exponential!

Comment: I think that we can use the Uniqueness result by Peano, which requires the right-hand side function to be nonincreasing in $y$.
As $\mathrm{e}^{x}\geq1$ is obvious for $x\geq0$, we need to show that $y:=\mathrm{e}^{-x}>0$ for $x\geq0$. Note that $y^{\prime}=-y$ (decreasing in $y$) and $y(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming uniform convergence of the series you can show by termwise differentiation that $f(x) = e^x$ verifies $f'(x) = f(x).$

Clearly $e^x = \sum_k \frac{x^k}{k!}$ is strictly positive for all positive $x$ therefore it is an increasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$. Consider the set $A = \{x < 0 : e^x \leq 0 \}$ and assume that it is non empty.

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $A$ that converges to $L$. Then $L \in A$ by continuity of $f$ 
$$ f(L) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n) =  \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \leq 0.$$

Therefore $a := \sup A \in A$ and $a < 0$ and $e^a \leq 0$.

If $e^a < 0$ then notice that $e^0 = 1$ and by the intermediate value theorem there exists $ a < c < 0$ such that $e^c = 0$ and $c \in A$ which contradicts the maximality of $a$.

If $e^a = 0$ then consider $$C = \{c' \leq a \; \vert \forall x \in (c',a], \; \;f(x) = 0 \}.$$ If $\inf C = k > - \infty$, then $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. the interval $[k- \delta, k + \delta]$ around $k$ is such that $f > 0$ on $[k- \delta, k)$ or $f < 0$ on $[k- \delta,k)$.

Since $f$ is equal to its own derivative it is either positive-increasing or negative increasing on $(k-\delta,k$). In both cases by the mean value theorem, $\exists \alpha \in (k-\delta/2,k)$ s.t. 
$$ f'(\alpha) = \frac{f(k) - f(k- \delta/2)}{\delta/2} = - \frac{f(k-\delta/2)}{\delta/2} $$
This is a contradiction since $f'(\alpha) = f(\alpha)$ and $f(k- \delta/2)$ have the same sign and are both not equal to zero.

If $\inf C' = - \infty$ then $e^x = 0 \forall x \leq a.$ We must proceed differently:

Consider the function $F : \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto F(x) = \int_{a+x}^0 e^t \;dt$

Clearly $$F(x) = [e^t]_{a+x}^0 = 1 - e^{a+x}.$$

Using the change of variable $u(t) = t - x $ in the integral we get

$$ F(x) = \int_{x+a}^0 e^t dt = \int_{a}^{-x} e^t dt = [e^t]^{-x}_a = e^{-x} - e^a = e^{-x}$$

Therefore $\forall x > 0$:

$$ 1 - e^{a + x} = e^{-x}.$$

Since $e^t > 0 \; \forall t > a$ the exponential function is increasing on $(a, + \infty)$  so

$$a + x > 0 \Rightarrow  e^{a + x} > e^{0} = 1 \iff F(x) = 1 - e^{a+x} < 0.$$

But $ a + x > 0 \Rightarrow -x < a$ and $e^{-x} = 0$ so $$F(x) = e^{-x} = 0$$
which is a contradiction.

We conclude that $A = \{ x < 0 : e^x \leq 0 \} = \varnothing$ and the exponential function is positive everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The series expansion is
$$
e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots
$$
For $x\ge0$ we have $1$ and a bunch of nonnegative numbers, so the result is clearly positive.

For $x<0$ notice that:
$$
\frac1{e^x}=e^{-x}
$$
So positivity of $e^x$ clearly implies that $e^{-x}$ is positive.

Comment: Put $x:=-20$ in your second displayed formula!

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Right, okay, if $x<-1$ then you should group them with $1$ seperate, good point.

Comment: I **cannot** say that the proof is **rigorious**.

Comment: I guess you could do this instead.

Comment: Note that you have used the semi group property $\mathrm{e}^{x}\mathrm{e}^{-x}=\mathrm{e}^{0}=1$,
which is an infraction of the rule.

Comment: @bkarpuz It becomes difficult to rearrange the terms for $x<-1$. It would be easier to prove that $e^xe^{-x}=1$ using the series expansion.